# From where to change the path of assets to src folder?

Tags: angular, http

I know when we have to fetch local JSON file we need to save in assets folder, and you can fetch eaisly from there.

But I want to know where angular will set that configuration to fetch only from assets folder not from src folder, what if I want to fetch local JSON file from src folder ?

PS: After search i found `.angular-cli.json` file where i think angular set configuration for same but i am not clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can set it in `.angular-cli.json` like you mentioned. Specifically in here,

```
{
 "apps": [
  {
   "assets": [
    "assets", // <-- any additional folders goes in here
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: there are already given `assets` folder, so you mean i have to add `srs` too in the list right ?

Comment: tried with same but not working, have you tried using this ?